# i can't make a contact between the activities in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello this is my first app with kotlin i am trying to make annual rate calculation app the problem is i have 4 activities every activity own button and edit's texts
i wan't when The User click the button, the program get the numbers from Edit's texts and only make the calculation and save it somewhere and same work for the activity 2 and 3.
but when he click the last button of the last activity i want to call all the results and show it in ViewText

**The Question is:How to save data Every time somewhere and call when i need it?**

First Activity

```
      class st {
     var int_P: Double? = null
     var ctl_P: Double? = null


     public constructor(int_P: Any, ctl_P: Any) {
         this.int_P = int_P.toString().toDouble()  //Physique
         this.ctl_P = ctl_P.toString().toDouble()



     public fun GetMP(): Double {
         return (this.int_P!! + (this.ctl_P!! * 2)) / 3
     }

 }

             Btn_Next1.setOnClickListener ({
            var int_P = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(edit_IP.text.toString()) //Physique
            var ctl_P = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(edit_CP.text.toString())


            var ss = st(int_P,ctl_P)

            val ic = Intent(this, Sec_Act::class.java)
            startActivity(ic)

        })
```

(Secend and Third Activity Same)

Activity 4

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener ({

        var act1 = MainActivity.st().GetMC()
        Textv.text = act1.toString()
    })
```

With this method i got problem (no value passed for parameter int_P , ctl_P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to send information back to an Activity:

1. onActivityResult(),
2. having a singleton class,
3. use Shared Preferences,
4. headless fragments,
5. sqlite database,
6. store the information in a file.
7. Intents
8. receivers

You need to determine which will be the best solution for you.  Whether it's kotlin or java, the methodology will be the same.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say thank you that's helped me alot